# Unable to get member permissions from messageCreate

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I've made an automod system which only moderates users who don't have Administrator. For some reason I keep getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'permissions')'. Here's the code:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR)) return;
```

Comment: Member returns null outside of a guild. Make sure you're sending the message in a server

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to Discord.JS. I'm not DMing the bot or anything, but it still gives this error.

Comment: Are you writing your message in a server?

Comment: Yeah I am, I think I've fixed it just by adding the line if (!message.member) return

Comment: For others having this issue, assuming they know for sure that they have the necessary intents, are not referencing DMs, etc., I recently discovered a pattern with `message.member` being `null` when the author of the message is a bot. This may be the issue for you. I fixed this issue by checking if `message.author.bot` is true, and getting the member from the cache manually via `message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)`. Worked like a charm. Using `message.fetch()` might work as well. Not sure why this issue occurs when its solution is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

you need to require PermissionFlagsBits from discord.js

then on your code change it from:

```
if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR)) return;
```

to

```
if (message.member.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator)) return;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your dependencies with `npm update`

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried adding a Const?

```
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');
```